# Map observable<t> in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have function that calls an api. The api returns an array of objects. I want to map the response to an observable of type Business. I am not quite sure how to correctly map this in the getBusiness function.

Sample Response

```
[
  {
    Id: 2,
    Name: "Joe"
  }
]
```

```
export interface Business {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

```
getBusiness(): Observable<Business[]> {

        const url = "";

        return this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          map((data: Business[]) => data as Business[] )
        )
      }
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss'],
})
export class Component implements OnInit {

this.apiService.getBusiness() {
      .subscribe((res: Business[]) => console.log(res))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You call map on the array

```
map((data: Business[]) => data.map(business => ({ id: business.Id, name: business.Name })) )
```

If you are developing the API you should be able to set it to use camelcase so you don't have to do this everywhere. If not you could write a function that lowercase the first letter of each property.

```js
const firstLetterLower = val => val[0].toLowerCase() + val.substring(1);

const camelcase = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) => {
  result[firstLetterLower(key)] = obj[key];
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(camelcase({
  Id: 2,
  Name: "Joe"
}));
```

Then you could use

```
map((data: Business[]) => data.map(business => camelcase(business))
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO you do not need to cast this at the service.

Also why is `const url = "";`,  ?

**Service - Make sure the URL is correct**

```
getBusiness() {
    return this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions);
}
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getBusiness().subscribe(
     (res: Business[]) => console.log(res)
    );    
}
```

**If you need to do this in a better standard way (sometimes it is overkill)**

**Have a look at NgRx/Store**

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. You could directly type your data during the http call : `return this._http.get<Business[]>(...);`. But ngrx isn't necessary, just doing this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You type responses from the httpclient like so:

```
return this.http.get<Business[]>(url, this.httpOptions)
```

All there is to it. This gives typing information to the compiler only and doesn’t change the response. If you need to actually modify the response structure to have different property names, you’ll have to Do that manually in a map or something.